# Grafana 6.6+ admin role assignment for keycloak user

Tags: grafana, grafana-variable

By default keycloak user is getting viewer premission when we use login with keycloak option in Grafana. Is it possible to get the admin premission for keycloak user?

Answer (score 1):

Configure `role_attribute_path` properly.

See examples in the doc https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/auth/generic-oauth/

Comment: Configured role_attribute_path = Admin and also configured role_attribute_path= role_attribute_path = contains(info.groups[*], 'admin') && 'Admin' || contains(info.groups[*], 'editor') && 'Editor' || 'Viewer'. But it didn't worked for me?? Is there anything I am missing here??